# Overloading operator= for struct members of class std::vector<>

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Say I have the following struct:

```
struct Parameter {
  double value;
  double error;
};
```

So that I'm usually working with vectors of that struct (ie. `std::vector<Parameter>`), and ocasionally I want to set a vector of *values* (but not *errors*) in that vector of parameters by using the `operator=` with a standard std::vector, for convenience.

```
std::vector<Parameter> vector_of_parameters;
std::vector<double> vector_of values;
....
vector_of_parameters = vector_of_values;
```

To do so, I'm trying to overload `operator=` for this struct as follows:

```
std::vector<Parameter> operator=(const std::vector<double>& v) {
  this->clear();
  for (const auto& i:v) {
    Parameter p;
    p.value = i;
    this->push_back(p);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

But this will return an error saying that **std::vector operator=(const std::vector& v) must be a non-static member**. So if I understand it correctly, I have to define this as a member function of the operator as:

```
std::vector<Parameter>::operator=(const std::vector<double>& v) {
  this->clear();
  for (const auto& i:v) {
    Parameter p;
    p.value = i;
    this->push_back(p);
  }
  return *this;
}
```

The error now says that a **syntaxis with template<>**, but I dont really see it, or understand it, and don't know what more can I do.

Comment: You can't define a class member function (like `operator=`) that is not declared in the class (in include file `vector`). So you need to write a free function like `void assign(std::vector<Parameter> &out, const std::vector<double> &in)` or even better use `std::transform`.

Comment: Read [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) for more about copy assignment. You are correct that copy assignment must be a member function. But you are also trying to do template specialization of `std::vector` with your custom type `Parameter`, Look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std) for more about that.

Comment: not sure but it seems like you think structs are somehow different from classes. They are not.C++ has only classes that you can declare with either of the two keywords `struct` or `class`, the difference is only the default access of members and base classes.

Comment: You cannot overload assignment operators for classes that are not yours (such as std::vector). This is not allowed by the language, but it's not really important; the main problem is that it's just an extremely dangerous idea (and of course that's exactly the reason why the language doesn't allow it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot overload the assignment operator of `std::vector`.  `operator =` must be a member function and you just can't add a member function to `std::vector`.

What you can do is make a convenience function like `create_parameters` that takes a `std::vector<double>` and returns a `std::vector<Parameter>`.  That would look like

```
std::vector<Parameter> create_parameters(std::vector<double> const& params)
{
    std::vector<Parameter> ret(params.size());
    std::transform(params.begin(), params.end(), ret.begin(),
                   [](auto value) { return Parameter{value, 0}; });
    return ret;
}
```

and then

```
vector_of_parameters = vector_of_values;
```

would become

```
vector_of_parameters = create_parameters(vector_of_values);
```

Comment: While this looks promising, it returns me an error "expected primary-expression before ')'". I do not really understand the syntax inside std::transform and haven't been able to fix it.

Comment: @EuGENE Oops.  I missed a closing `}`, fixed now.  It is a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Now it works, thanks!! Very instructive answer by the way ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think that an alternative simple way to create `std::vector<Parameter>` from `std::vector<double>` is defining a single argument constructor `Parameter(double value)` which accepts the `Parameter::value`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <optional>

struct Parameter
{  
    double value;
    std::optional<double> error;

    explicit Parameter(double v) : value(v)
    {}
};
```

Then you can use *range-constructor* as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gcDyxN1lYkRtJGmv)

```
std::vector<Parameter> v_of_parameters(v_of_values.cbegin(), v_of_values.cend());
```